# OpenStack EC2 Ubuntu cloud image -- SSH host keys were changed after emegency reboot

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, ssh-keys, qcow2, data-consistency

Recently one of our servers was hanged due to IPMI BMC failure.
It is CentOS 6.3 OpenStack compute host serving KVM vitual machines with qcow2 backend.

There was running a VM based on EC2 Ubintu could image (precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img).

After the system reboot I found a strange thing: ssh host keys on VM were recreated (13:25 - reboot time):

```
root@weather:~# ll /etc/ssh/*key
-rw------- 1 root root  668 Nov 21 13:25 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw------- 1 root root  227 Nov 21 13:25 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Nov 21 13:25 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

I also found that some orphan i-nodes was deleted during FS recovery process:

```
Nov 21 13:25:23 weather kernel: [    0.901159] EXT4-fs (vda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Nov 21 13:25:23 weather kernel: [    0.902688] EXT4-fs (vda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
Nov 21 13:25:23 weather kernel: [    1.930773] EXT4-fs (vda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1286
......
Nov 21 13:25:23 weather kernel: [    1.940810] EXT4-fs (vda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 53755
Nov 21 13:25:23 weather kernel: [    1.940815] EXT4-fs (vda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 53754
Nov 21 13:25:23 weather kernel: [    1.940819] EXT4-fs (vda1): 8 orphan inodes deleted
```

My question is: why ssh keys could be recreated? Can it be a result of data loss in filesystem? And how to prevent this in the future?

qcow2 cache mode is set to write-through in libvirt VM configurations. Host filesystem is ZFS (zfsonlinux) placed on hardware RAID controller with BBU.

If this is a result of a file-system inconsistency on reboot - I am very mystified since 
ssh key files are not changed and all relevant data expected to be synced to stable media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noone's stepped in to say anything intelligent, so I'll state the obvious.

Yes, it could be as a result of data loss in the file system.  I can't speak for ubuntu, but the CentOS (RH-style) sshd startup scripts provide for automatic creation of the keys if they're missing, and I presume ubuntu does something similar.

**If** your VM's file system was corrupted as a result of the failure of the underlying host, **and** that corruption happened to take out the system's ssh keys, **then** I would expect them to be automatically regenerated, and therefore to have changed.

Is that what happened?  Sadly, at this point, I don't think anyone can tell.

If your system had been `tripwire`d, then you'd have some kind of baseline audit of the FS with which you could compare the current state in order to make a more-informed decision about what exactly had happened to the VM image.  As it is, you'll have to make a business decision as to whether this machine is sensitive enough to justify a complete clean rebuild, or whether you just shrug and accept it as one of those things.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a simple way to check for write-back caching  bugs in the storage stack?

Comment: Not that I know of!